# Find all people attending on certain date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, array-formulas

I have a Google spreadsheet which keeps track of people attending some courses which run over sever weeks. Here are just 2 courses but my actual spreadsheet has 20 courses and different numbers of people attending each course.

In column L, I want a formula which calculates the next open date that the course is running (because they are closed on certain weeks when the venue is unavailable). In rows 1 and 7, some weeks are "closed" and some weeks are listed as "refunded" meaning that the course is closed this week and the attendees are refunded for this week. So L2 should be 10 May, and L8 should be 27 Apr.

And in cell L3 and below, it should show who will be attending on the next open date. I'd like this arrayformula in cell L3 to do this for all of the courses down below in column L. How can I do this?

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Wednesday course |  |  |  | Closed |  |  | Refunded |  | Closed |  | Next date |
| 2 | First name | Last name | ID | 5 Apr | 12 Apr | 19 Apr | 26 Apr | 3 May | 10 May | 17 May | 24 May | ***10 May*** |
| 3 | John | Smith | 212 | y |  | y | y |  | y |  | y |  |
| 4 | Henry | Jones | 437 |  |  | y |  | y |  | y | y |  |
| 5 | Katie | Rogers | 894 |  | y |  |  | y | y |  | y |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | Thursday course |  |  |  |  | Refunded |  |  | Closed |  |  | Next date |
| 8 | First name | Last name | ID | 6 Apr | 13 Apr | 20 Apr | 27 Apr | 4 May | 11 May | 18 May | 25 May | ***27 Apr*** |
| 9 | Jordan | Davies | 014 | y | y | y | y |  |  | y |  |  |
| 10 | Rose | McKenzie | 709 |  |  | y |  | y |  | y | y |  |
| 11 | Raj | Patel | 338 |  | y |  |  | y | y |  | y |  |
| 12 | Nathan | Green | 338 | y | y |  | y | y | y | y | y |  |

Here's a shared Google spreadsheet:
[Google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tyr1W-I_RwpCp76IJTjs8guSJbBO1Glau_m1xrI7GXk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I've just added a link to the Google spreadsheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tyr1W-I_RwpCp76IJTjs8guSJbBO1Glau_m1xrI7GXk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a [solution here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tyr1W-I_RwpCp76IJTjs8guSJbBO1Glau_m1xrI7GXk/edit#gid=515618223). Please do test it out:

```
=let(Δ,scan(,byrow(U4:AP,lambda(Σ,if(isdate(index(Σ,,1)),+filter(column(Σ),Σ>=today(),not(regexmatch(offset(Σ,-2,),"Refund|Cancel"))),))),lambda(a,c,if(c<>"",c,a))),
       map(D4:D,Δ,lambda(Σ,Γ,if(Σ="",,index(offset(Σ,,-3,,42),,Γ)))))
```

[image]

---

***final updated formula***:

```
=let(Δ,scan(,byrow(U4:AP,lambda(Σ,if(isdate(index(Σ,,1)),+filter(column(Σ),Σ>=today(),not(regexmatch(offset(Σ,-2,),"Refund|Cancel"))),))),lambda(a,c,if(c<>"",c,a))),
       map(T4:T,Δ,lambda(Σ,Γ,if((Σ="Status")+(Σ="Week #"),,index(offset(Σ,,-19,,42),,Γ)))))
```

[image]

Comment: When I have any other text in the cell above the "First name" heading, the formula inserts a number in the row with the week numbers. Can you please see the spreadsheet?

Comment: Updated the formula in sheet.